# how to send a json array of objects as a response in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to hard code three key-value pairs as 
`[{code:"US",name:"United States"},{code:"CA",name:"Canada"}, {code:"MX",name:"Mexico"}]` etc.  and send the response as array list 
object in the format as [,].
I am accessing the value like country.code and country.name while iterating in the list but as of now i am send country as a object whilst i want it to go as a list inside which i want country as a object.

Here is the code :

```
  return $.ajax({
         url: '/commonDataCal/commondata',
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: data,
            locale: 'en_US',
         success: function(data) {
           if (data.CALError) {
            var CountryListResponse = [ country ];
               country = {code:"US", name:"United States"}, {code:"CA", name:"Canada"}, {code:"MX", name:"Mexico"};
                  success.call(this, CountryListResponse);
           } else if (data.CountryListResponse.successful) {
                  data.CountryListResponse.countryList.splice(230,1);
                  data.CountryListResponse.countryList.splice(169,1);
                  success.call(this, data.CountryListResponse.countryList);
                  } else {
                        error.call(this, data.CountryListResponse);
                  }
```

Comment: please try to describe what your problem is and make your code readable. how about reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting something? it's not that hard

Comment: `var CountryListResponse = [ country ]` : country is undefined. `country = {...}, {...}, {...}` : invalid syntax. `success.call(this` : success is undefined. Open you console, it's probably yelling errors.

Comment: Yes, that is why i am asking you the proper way to do it.